# MySQL Search Query on two different fields

Tags: mysql

I need to search on two fields using LIKE function and should match also in reverse order. My table uses InnoDB which dont have Full text search.

Consider the following case:

I have users table with first_name and last_name column. On it, there is a row with the following value:

```
{
    first_name: 'Ludwig',
    last_name: 'van Beethoven',
}
```

Cases:

1. Can search "Ludwig van Beethoven"
2. Can search "Beethoven Ludwig"
3. Can search "Ludwig"
4. Can search "Beethoven"

I tried this SQL statement but no luck.

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as fullname 
  FROM users 
 WHERE fullname LIKE '%Ludwig van Beethoven%';
```

Comment: At the moment, I am using this SQL statement. 

    SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ' , last_name) as fullname 
      FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 
    LIKE '%string%' AND CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) 
    LIKE '%string%';

And it works on all cases.

Answer (score 7):

You need to re-state the concat expression in your where clause.

```
 SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as fullname 
      FROM users 
     WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%doe%';
```

Unfortunately "as" just create a column alias, not a variable that you can use elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for (answer + reason) I lifted the query from my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: -1 functions shouldn't be used in WHERE clauses. Column aliases can be referenced using `HAVING`, see my answer.

Comment: @Andy: Absolutely agreed that you should avoid functions in `WHERE` clauses *where you have other options*, but they're not *automatically* bad, not if the function can be computed on an index (see my answer for what I mean by that). I don't think `HAVING` helps here (I compared execution plans; see the notes in my answer), but would be very interested in any references you have for why it might.

Answer (score 6):

#### The Main Thing

Make sure you have a compound index on `first_name` and `last_name`. Otherwise, it's *really easy* to end up doing a full table scan regardless of how you approach this. So if you don't already have one, create one:

```
CREATE INDEX users_firstandlast ON users(first_name, last_name);
```

#### Syntax Options

Once that index is in place, you have some options:

**Option 1**: As [Willis Blackburn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469359/mysql-search-query-on-two-different-fields/2469373#2469373) said, repeat the `CONCAT` in your `WHERE` clause (because `AS` doesn't create a name you can use in the `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as fullname 
FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%doe%';
```

Use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) to check in your specific situation, but in my tests it says it uses the compound index, even though you're using a function in the `WHERE` clause.

**Option 2**: In this *particular* case, you can always just use two `LIKE` s in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as fullname 
FROM users 
WHERE first_name LIKE '%doe%' or last_name LIKE '%doe%';
```

Again this can make use of the compound index (whereas it won't make use of individual indexes on the `first_name` and `last_name` columns -- it would if you weren't leading with a wildcard, but according to `EXPLAIN` [and your mileage may vary, always check], in that case it goes with the table scan).

**Option 3** In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469359/mysql-search-query-on-two-different-fields/2469519#2469519), Andy says you can use `HAVING` for this. My [read of the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id2738693) suggests it will first build the result set, and only then apply `HAVING` at the very end before sending it to the client, and so I'd be leery of this. **But**, in my quick and dirty tests, `EXPLAIN` tells me that if you have the compound index I mentioned above, the `HAVING` version does an index search, not a table scan. If your tests with real data bear that out, that may be a good option for you. This use of `HAVING` in this way is a MySQL extension (not standard), but then again, so is `CONCAT` so we're already into MySQL-specific stuff. :-) But again, double-check in your real life environment.

#### Conclusion

Create the index if you don't already have it, then I'd go with Option 2 if it's remotely a possibility; otherwise, option 1 unless you can find (or Andy can provide) a reference for the `HAVING` thing not building a massive interim result set (it would be really cool, if non-standard, if it didn't). Regardless, check with `EXPLAIN`, and test, in your specific environment.

Comment: is it possible or need, to create a relevance index to push the closest results on top, or mysql do it implicitly?

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%Ludwig%' OR CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) LIKE '%Ludwig%';

All search cases where returned including 'Beethoven Ludwig'.

Answer (score -2):

When you CONCAT() two columns the LIKE become case sensitive. So this should find you results but isn't optimal for performance:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS fullname FROM users 
WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)) LIKE LOWER('%doe%');
```

That's getting MySQL to do work on each row though.

Comment: *"When you CONCAT() two columns the LIKE become case sensitive"* Really? Do you have a reference for that? I'm not seeing why how you create the value would have any effect on whether it's case sensitive or not.

Comment: Update: Didn't see anything in the docs and just tried it. **No,** the concat does not make the `like` operator suddenly case sensitive, at least not in my MySQL 5.1 installs (Windows and Ubuntu) using either MyISAM or InnoDB tables (and it really shouldn't be storage-specific): http://pastie.org/875248

Comment: This was an issue last time I did this, perhaps it's now been addressed. I blogged about it at the time.

http://www.serberus.net/2007/06/24/case-sensitivity-in-mysql/

Comment: In your blog post, you don't say what version it was. In 2007 I'm thinking 5.0, but...  I kicked around the MySQL bugs database for a while, but there are just too many results (most of which being people misunderstanding how `like` should work, but at least one being a real bug -- but fixed in v4.1.11 a couple of years before your post). Apparently the collation setting may be an issue as well, but none of the ones I looked at (which was a small subset of the total) were about using a function causing this, which really would be very strange.