# Database - the best way, how to search names

Tags: mysql, database, search

I am solving in these days following situation:
In my DB table I have columns for name and surname.

On my page I have input for searching people, and I am struggling with a problem, how to search the name in database that is stored in two columns and I have the name as string (`"Joe Green"`).

For example, in database I have followings:

```
Joe New
Joe Blue
Joe Green
Joe Francois Green
```

What could be the best way, how this problem to solve? I am currently working with MySQL database and Rails 3.

EDIT: Thank you guys for you replies, **but I don't know, how to make the query in Rails 3 notation, is it possible to use "concat"?**

Comment: So "Joe" is in one column and "New"/"Blue"/"Francois Green" in another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your database table engine is **myISAM** then  use **[FULLTEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)**

first create **FULLTEXT** index by

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_name ON pages (name, surname)
```

then  use below query to retrieve required data

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   MATCH(name,surname) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

### update

**alternative:use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**

first create index

```
CREATE INDEX users_firstandlast ON users(name, surname);
```

**option1:** repeat the `CONCAT` in your `WHERE` clause (because AS doesn't create a name you can use in the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) as fullname 
FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%joe green%';
```

**option 2:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) as fullname 
FROM users 
WHERE name LIKE '%joegreen%' or surname LIKE '%joegreen%';
```

**[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469359/mysql-search-query-on-two-different-fields)**

Comment: I tried to do by your idea and I got this query - **SELECT `persons`.* FROM `persons` WHERE (concat(name, surname) like '%Joe Green%')**. And the result of this query is nothing - I didn't get the name

Comment: why you enclosed your `where` condition in `(` ??

Comment: Rails makes it automatically - **Person.find(:all, :conditions => ["concat(name, surname) like ?", "%#{params[:search][:name]}%"])**

Answer (score 3):

A lot of this would be significantly simpler if you had given some indication of what language is being used at the interface between the input and the database (since Rails is usually associated with Ruby I'll assume you mean that), however....

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) 
      LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(?,' ', '%'),'%')
ORDER BY LEVENSTEIN(CONCAT(name, ' ', surname), ?)
```

(where '?' is replaced by your search string, and the [levenstein function is described here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552))

Performance will be poor - a better solution would be to split the string Ruby and attempt matches of varying combinations.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:
* split user's input to words
* search each word in name and surname columns

Answer (score 1):

first use the split function to split the string

> namearr = name.split

```
namestr = ""
namearr.each do |i|
  namestr = namestr + i
end
```

then use the values in your query

> stmt = "select * from mytable where CONCAT(firstname,surename)= " + namestr

Comment: And what if I provide three words?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the sql server full text search which i do not recommend because of the performance is very bad ,or use the lucin .net which is more powerful and her are some links :
http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

mark as answered if it helps :)

Comment: Of course I will mark the question as answered, but I still can't to get the way, how to do in Rails 3...